# Textual Examples of Honorifics used (contemporary/historical）

Tags: simplified-characters, classical-chinese

Could anyone recommend some texts or videos where Chinese honorifics are used? I have a list of types of Chinese honorifics but not any **textual** examples.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is asking for something that can be easily found by a few searches on the Internet, which was obviously not done by OP

Comment: I am voting to close this question because the question is too general, ask more specifically and you will get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Give me some honorifics that you wanna know about. I can give you some daily life examples.

For example, the most simple honorific in Chinese is 您, which means you. You can use it to anyone to whom you want to show respect. Usually it's to strangers, somebody older than you or someone at higher position than you (in a professional environment).

Comment: The only other I can think of is 大人

Comment: I have an list that I collected ranging from: 称呼自己的谦称 , 职业称谓性敬语, 人称敬语,亲属敬语 and 常用的雅言.

Comment: :D Nowadays 大人 just means adults. In ancient times, 大人 is how lower rank officers/soldiers call their superior officers or anyone who has higher social class than him, as in English "Sir".

Comment: For @jinbu1, your list is a list of different categories of honorifics.

Comment: @YitongM. ,right. I am looking for places where they might occur such as; books, letter, news articles etc.